# How to display values inside pivot table using eloquent in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.1

I have this enrollment project, that a student will only choose the subjects he/she wants to enroll. Those subject will be fetch automatically and be displayed on a table. [See this image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WyChe.jpg) After the student will click on the add button of the enrollment form, the subject will be added to the [added subjects form.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O47IF.jpg) However I am having problem displaying the values of all sections and subjects define on my pivot table which is the section_subject. How can I achieve this? I already define belongsToMany relationships on the Section Model and Subject Model. Here's my code.

Subject.php

```
class Subject extends Model
{
    public function sections()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Section::class);
    }
}
```

Section.php

```
class Section extends Model
{
    public function subjects()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Subject::class);
    }
}
```

ReservationController class

```
class ReservationController extends Controller
{
    public function create($id)
    {
        $subjects = Subject::with('sections')->get();

        return view('reservation.form',compact('subjects'));
    }
}
```

form.blade.php

```
<tr>
  <th>Section</th>
  <th>Subject Code</th>
  <th>Descriptive Title</th>
  <th>Schedule</th>
  <th>No. of Units</th>
  <th>Room</th>
  <th>Action</th>
  </tr>
  <body>
  @foreach($subjects as $subject)
    <tr>
      <td>{{ $subject->section_code }}</td>
      <td>{{ $subject->subject_code }}</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>{{ $subject->units }}</td>
      <td>Df</td>
      <td>
         <button class="btn btn-xs btn-primary">Add</button>
         <button class="btn btn-xs btn-info">Edit</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
   @endforeach
```

Here's the section_subject table

```
Schema::create('section_subject', function (Blueprint $table) {

  $table->integer('section_id')->unsigned();
  $table->integer('subject_id')->unsigned();

  $table->foreign('section_id')
        ->references('id')
        ->on('sections')
        ->onDelete('cascade');

  $table->foreign('subject_id')
        ->references('id')
        ->on('subjects')
        ->onDelete('cascade');

  $table->primary(['section_id', 'subject_id']);
});
```

Also, here are the subjects table and section table respectively.

```
Schema::create('subjects', function (Blueprint $table) {
  $table->increments('id');
  $table->integer('department_id')->unsigned();
  $table->string('subject_code');
  $table->string('subject_description');
  $table->integer('units');
  $table->integer('cost');
  $table->timestamps();
});

Schema::create('sections', function (Blueprint $table) {
  $table->increments('id');
  $table->integer('instructor_id')->unsigned();
  $table->string('section_code');
  $table->string('section_description');
  $table->string('room_no');
  $table->date('schedule');
  $table->date('semester');
  $table->timestamps();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `{{ $subject->pivot->section_code }}`

Also, add this to relation:

```
->withPivot('section_code')
```

More on getting data from pivot tables [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many).

Comment: Thanks. But Im having this error SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'section_subject.section_code' in 'field list' (SQL: select `sections`.*, `section_subject`.`subject_id` as `pivot_subject_id`, `section_subject`.`section_id` as `pivot_section_id`, `section_subject`.`section_code` as `pivot_section_code` from `sections` inner join `section_subject` on `sections`.`id` = `section_subject`.`section_id` where `section_subject`.`subject_id` in (1, 2, 3))

Comment: Show relationships please.

Comment: You didn't add `->withPivot('section_code')` to relation, please try to do that.

Comment: No in my project code I already did that but im having the error as mention in my above comment.

Comment: I just remove it from the question above. But I already added it.

Answer (score 0):

If I am right you want to get all the subjects and sections that are present in the pivot table. If that is the case then you can make a new model SectionSubject and pull the distinct data from it.

Model SectionSubject:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class SectionSubject extends Model {

    public function section()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Section::class);
    }
    public function subject()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Subject::class);
    }
}
```

And then in Controller where you need it define this model as:

```
use App\SectionSubject;
```

And finally you can query out all the Sections and Subjects as:

```
$sections = SectionSubject::distinct()->select('section_id')->with('section')->get();
$subjects = SectionSubject::distinct()->select('subject_id')->with('subject')->get();
```

This gives you all the subjects and sections in the pivot table. I hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks but I think you dont need to create a SectionSubject model. You just need to create a pivot table.